# Como puedo elegir cuantos resultados mostrar en una vista de la llamada a un stored procedure en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, stored-procedure

tengo un stored con su parámetro que me devuelve una tabla de más de 8 filas con 6 columnas.
Hago la llamada desde mi controller y paso el resultado a mi vista.
Para mostrar la columna que deseo en mi vista utilizo un foreach el cual me devuelve en mi vista los más de 8 resultados que contiene la columna.

Quisiera que solo me mostrara uno el que yo desee, ya sea el primero el ultimo o cual sea pero que sea solo uno.

No tengo acceso al stored como para modificarlo o algo así, así que mi única solución es por código.

Les muestro mis codigos:

controller

```
$IdUsuarioSuc = $request->input('usuario');

$kard = (DB::select('{call Proc_usuario_sucursal(?)}',[$IdUusarioSuc]));

    return view('kard')->with($kard);
```

Vista

```
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="datos">

            <div class="card">
                @foreach($kard as $kardx)
                    <p>{{ $kardx->SucAsistida}}</p>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Si la consulta te devuelve una coleccion, puedes acceder al primer o ultimo elemento con las funciones [first()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-first) y [last()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-last), O acceder a algun elemento especifico por su indice, ej `$kardx[1]`. Por favor aclara tu problema actualizalizando la pregunta

Comment: Encontré la solución y justo así es como me comentas, no sabía muy bien que hacia el foreach y lo que hace es que recorre todo el array.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la respuesta a mi problema, la respondo por si puede ser de ayuda.

De la sig manera eliges en específico por el índice del array y el nombre de la columna que desees, esto iría en la view en donde quieras mostrar tu información.

```
{{$kard[0]->NombreColumna}}
```